# java maintain insertion order in map

Tags: java, data-structures

I am initializing a map with a bunch of values. The order of the values is important, and when I do myMap.values(), I'd like them to all come out in the order they went in. What data structure should I be using for that?

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new SomeKindOfMap<String, String>();
myMap.put(key1, value1)
myMap.put(key2, value2)
//etc
```

Comment: Try [`LinkedHashMap`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html).

Comment: Perfect, looks like what I need thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for a [`LinkedHashMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html). Pro tip: If you go to the JavaDoc for an interface like [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), there's a "All Known Implementing Classes" section where you can see a list of all implementations in the JDK, and see if any meet your needs...

Comment: Upvt: That ProTip may seem trivial but it truly has helped me a lot.

Comment: @pulp_fiction: Me too. :-)